# Why is this random generator sometimes returning 3 digits instead of 4?

Tags: python

```
if choice == '1':
    print('Your card has been created')
card = create_card()
print(f'Your card number:\n{card}')
pin = int(''.join(f'{random.randint(0, 9)}' for _ in range(4)))
print(f'Your card PIN:\n{pin}\n')
cards.append([card, pin])
```

Please can someone explain why the above code sometimes generates a 3-digit number as opposed to a 4-digit number? For example:
[image: here]

Comment: `int('0123')` is…?

Comment: Your original code was good enough, by the way.

Comment: @Ry- No, it doesn't generate the zero. Please check my updated example.

Comment: Your updated code doesn't demonstrate that. Can `random.randint(0, 9)` return a `0`? Yes. Can that `0` appear at the first number in the string? Yes.

Comment: @msanford Sorry, I just updated with a larger chunk of the code to make it clearer what I was doing in the example. It doesn't generate the 'zero' as Ry- puts it.

Comment: @msanford Sorry, I don't understand - doesn't demonstrate what? As in my attached example, it generated '273' as opposed to '0273'

Comment: @BirbCS the `''.join(...)` part will generate `'0273'`. However, after you pass it through the surrounding `int()`, it is converted to `273`. That's why you see `273` and not `0273`

Comment: @MoonCheesez Yep I understand now, completely forgot about that! But then using what the others have suggested, however, means that I can't generate numbers with leading zeros.

Comment: If you want to keep the leading zeros, then just keep the number as a string - don't apply `int()` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your logic, it's possible to generate a string that starts with `0`. If you pass a leading 0 numeric string to `int()`, that leading 0 is ignored:

```py
print(int("0999"))
```

#### Output

```
999
```

To fix this, you could just change the range start value.

```py
pin = int(''.join(f'{random.randint(1, 9)}' for _ in range(4)))
```

**Edit:** To prove this to yourself, print both the generated string and the result of the `int()` function, like below.

```py
for i in range(100):
    st = ''.join(f'{random.randint(0, 9)}' for _ in range(4))
    print(st, int(st))
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that this will reduce the entropy of the resulting number since it won't have any `0`s at all.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I see - I completely forgot about that. Only issue, as msanford points out, is that I can't generate numbers with leading zeros. Any way around that?

Comment: You'll have to store the data as a string. Unless I'm severely mistaken, there's no way to represent a leading-zero integer with int.

Comment: Another idea is to store the PIN as a hash, preferably salted. PINs shouldn't be stored as human-readable data anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Others have explained why you sometimes end up with three-digit (or even two- or one-digit) results.  You could view this as a formatting problem -- printing a number with leading zeroes to a specified width.  Python does have features supporting that.

But I urge you to instead recognize that the problem is really that your data isn't actually a number in the first place.  Rather, it is a *string* of digits, all of which are always significant.  The easiest and best thing to do, then, is to simply **keep it as a string** instead of converting it to a number.

Comment: Yes, now that I understand what's the issue, I completely agree. Effectively, the leading zero doesn't have any significance when carrying out mathematical operations, thus python doesn't really need to keep it when using it as an actual number. This makes a whole lot more sense, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Your random generator is not returning four-digit numbers sometimes since it is putting a zero as the first digit. Numbers like 0322 are created by the random generator and it is being converted to 322. This generator can also make two-digit and one-digit numbers because of the zeros in front. If you want four-digit numbers only use `pin = random.randint(1000, 9999)`. If you want numbers with leading zeros, use `pin = ''.join(f'{random.randint(0, 1)}' for _ in range(4))`. This keeps the leading zeros. Keeping the pin as a string stops the leading zeros from being removed.

Comment: Yes thank you, that was the issue. However, is there really no way to generate four-digit numbers with leading zeros?

Comment: Try using a string instead of an integer. Try `pin = ''.join(f'{random.randint(0, 1)}' for _ in range(4))`

Comment: Yes, I will have to store it as string. Thanks.